# How I can add / mark order to see if was printed - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, admin, orders

how I can mark or add something in the order to see if this order was printed?

I have more admin users that print orders, I need to know what order has been viewed and printed and which haven't.

Comment: **Magento 2- add/mark an order to see if was printed:**, Magento does not have any business logic like that. You need to build your self.

Comment: I know this already, for this I add my question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create a sales order attribute,

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup $salesSetup */
$salesSetup = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

$printAttribute = [
    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'default' => 0,
    'comment' => 'PDF Print Status'
];

/** Sales Order Attributes */
$salesSetup->addAttribute('order', 'pdf_print_status', $printAttribute);
```

Then you need to observe the event `controller_action_postdispatch_sales_order_pdfinvoices` and there you can view the order ids from the action request data where you can update the order data.

Get request data in observer `execute` method -

```
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('request');
$params = $request->getParams();
```

Params data dump example:

```
2018-06-07 10:56:06 params: Array
(
    [key] => 1cafb9cde6c2edcb1789cc3d7ab472be03e81f120329ce407daa522c012155e7
    [selected] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 11
        )

    [filters] => Array
        (
            [placeholder] => true
        )

    [search] => 
    [namespace] => sales_order_grid
    [form_key] => Heszdoq6pQtxYJ2k
)
```

Here you can get the order id using `$params['selected']` and iterate id to save data in order.

```
if(isset($params['selected']) && !empty($params['selected'])) {
    foreach($params['selected'] as $order_id) {
        try {
            /** \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory */
            $orderFactory = $this->_orderFactory->create();
            $order = $orderFactory->load($order_id);
            if(isset($order) && $order->getId()) {
                $order->setData('pdf_print_status', 1);
                $order->setId($order_id)->save();
            }
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I need to create a module for this? or where I need to add all this?

Comment: You should create an extension or you can do  existing extension  that is your call

Comment: Yes, you need add a module for this, you can get plenty tutorials for creating custom module and add InstallData to add attribute create code and how to use event observer.

Comment: Can you do this for me please? I am not so good developer

Comment: sorry, i cant do that for you..!! You may want to hire a developer for that.

Comment: Please mark it as an excepted answer if that helps.!

Comment: I will wait much more time maybe someone can give me the correct code, anyway thanks for your time.

Comment: if you can add here the complete code to work this will help all, not only me. thanks